# Merge two sources into one feed.xml

Tags: jekyll, liquid

My Jekyll side uses the default `feed.xml`. I would like to change that because I have `site.posts` and `site.screencasts`. Both have the needed attributes to be shown in `feed.xml`. The default runs this loop:

```
{% for post in site.posts limit:10 %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

Is there a way to merge `site.posts` and `site.screencasts` and than sort them by date and than limit the result to 10?

Comment: `site.screencasts` what is this ? Are they inheriting from the post or page class ? Show me the code !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your `site.screencasts` are derived from page or post and all have a `date` in front matter.

Starting with an empty array helper in `_config.yml`

```
emptyArray: []
```

Then :

```
{% assign pagesArray = site.emptyArray %}
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% assign pagesArray = pagesArray | push: post %}
{% endfor %}
{% for scr in site.screencasts %}
  {% assign pagesArray = pagesArray | push: scr %}
{% endfor %}
{% assign sorted = pagesArray | sort: "date" %}
{% for s in sorted  limit: 10 %}
<h1>{{ s.title }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: If you don't want to add something to your `_config.yml` you can instead do: `{% assign updates = "" | split: "" %}` to get an empty list.